# How to make Windows 10 do nothing in background

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, windows-services

Is it possible in the most current Windows 10 to turn off absolutely every background process not vital to the OS existence?

Can I reach a state where only a software I explicitly launched, Plug & Play functionality, window manager and superfetch are working, and nothing else is using the CPU, RAM and hard drive?

If not in Windows 10, is it possible in Windows 7?

Comment: Actually you can not stop the processes that itself used for running the windows

Comment: @vaku That's what I meant when I said "not vital to the OS existence". There surely should be processes of the kernel, device manager, window system & desktop environment and a couple of others I am not that much aware of. I'm not talking about them.

Comment: [Windows 10 LTSB](https://www.howtogeek.com/273824/windows-10-without-the-cruft-windows-10-ltsb-explained/) might be of interest to you

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Whoa, LTSB surely looks like a great start! Thank you for information. However, automatic updates are only part of the picture. I am pretty sure that Windows constantly does something else in the background apart from the updates, HDD defrag and file search indexing first come to my mind. My question is what else is there which I don't know about and am I able to disable all that? I'll copy that note in the question text.

Comment: Perhaps you better explain what your end goal is. Does it have to be a Windows 10 Version? Would Windows Core suffice? Depending on your end goal but perhaps Windows is not the right system for you and you need a RTOS (which Windows is not)

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers I want a desktop system where the only software which is running is the kernel, the business software which I explicitly launched, the windows (rendering) system itself, Plug & Play functionality, network and, arbitrarily, superfetch because it's kinda innocent in Windows. I know that with literally _any_ Linux distro I can achieve that, and with Windows 98&XP I could achieve that, because there were not *that* many services in them. But is it possible with Windows 10? And no, I will not switch to other OS because of the software I use.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Windows Core does not have Win32 API support === useless.